# Last letter change in a word heavi to heavy

Tags: python

I have 2 words where I need to remove suffix "ness" from - sadness and heaviness.
"Sadness" is pretty easy but I am having issue with "heaviness"
I can remove "ness" but how do I change "i" to "y" to finish with "heavy"?

```
def remove_suffix_ness(word):
    word_split = list(word)
    without_ness = word_split[:-4]
    if without_ness[:-5] == "i":
        replace_letter = without_ness.replace("i", "y")
        print("".join(replace_letter))
    else:
        print("".join(without_ness))
```

Comment: You ask a question, then post some code that will do roughly what you want. It needs refinement (You only want to replace the last "i", and add a check for "-ness" as a suffix. I'm not clear what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

With [this sort of task](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) it may be hard to handle all the edge cases. It could be a good idea to use a battle-tested library such as [`nltk`](https://www.nltk.org/).

```
>>> import nltk.stem.lancaster
>>> stemmer = nltk.stem.lancaster.LancasterStemmer()
>>> stemmer.stem("happiness")
'happy'
>>> stemmer.stem("sadness")
'sad'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
def remove_suffix_ness(word):
    if word.endswith("ness"):
        if word[:-4].endswith("i"):
            return word[:-5] + "y"
        else:
            return word[:-4]
```

Test:

```
print(remove_suffix_ness("sadness"))  # Output: sad
print(remove_suffix_ness("heaviness"))  # Output: heavy
```

Answer (score -1):

If these are the only two words you need to perform the function on perhaps something like this is what you require:

```
def remove_suffix_ness(word):
    if word.endswith("ness" ):
        without_ness = word[ : -4 ]

        if without_ness.endswith("i" ):
            replace_letter = without_ness[ : -1] + "y"
            print(replace_letter)

        else:
            print(without_ness)

    else:
        print(word)
```